# Spring + Thymeleaf Engine Error Handling and Logging

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, splunk, custom-error-handling

Our company is in the process of switching our template engine from Velocity to Thymeleaf. We use Splunk for our logging, and with Velocity we were able to implement `org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogChute` to handle custom logging (format for and log to our splunk log), but I have been unable to find any similar class for Thymeleaf.

I've tried a couple of approaches so far. First, I tried to extend the actual Thymeleaf engine and add a try/catch wrapper around the process method, but that method is final, unfortunately. I saw a suggestion to add a filter to catch the thymeleaf errors, but something must be swallowing the error, because it never reaches that catch block.

The only option I can think of at this point is to simply pull `org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine` logs into our splunk log, but then it won't be properly formatted for ingestion and I can't add any custom fields.

Does anybody have any ideas?

EDIT:

Wow, so I just retried the Filter approach and it worked, but the caught exception was `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException`, so JRebel must not have reloaded my changes to catch `Exception` instead of `TemplateEngineException` when I tried it last.

That said, if anybody has a better approach, I'd love to hear it.
I'm new to the whole question posting thing; should I post an answer?

Comment: Use Spring Integration Adapter check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLoPpKq3JgU You can post your answer and accept it until a better answer is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter approach did end up working, but the `TemplateEngineException` is wrapped around by a `NestedServletException`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException;
import org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateEngineException;

/**
 * Filter to catch Thymeleaf template errors
 */
public class ThymeleafErrorFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } catch (final NestedServletException nse) {
            if(nse.getCause() instanceof TemplateEngineException) {
                //Do stuff here
                ...
            }

            throw nse;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

And then registering the filter

```
    /**
     * @return thymeleaf error filter
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean thymeleafErrorFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean thymeleafErrorFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        thymeleafErrorFilter.setName("thymeleafErrorFilter");
        thymeleafErrorFilter.setFilter(new ThymeleafErrorFilter());
        thymeleafErrorFilter.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return thymeleafErrorFilter;
    }
```